# Update Duplicate Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Calisma Database and it has DosyaNo and SiraNo columns.
I want to set SiraNo where DosyaNo is same for example

```
DosyaNo ____________SiraNo
0.00000000__________1
0.00000000__________2
0.00000000__________3
0.00000000__________4
0.00000000__________5
---------------------
0.10000000__________1
0.10000000__________2
0.10000000__________3
0.10000000__________4
0.10000000__________5
-----------------------
0.70000000__________1
0.70000000__________2
0.70000000__________3
------------------------
7.10000000__________1
7.10000000__________2
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific of your desired output?

Comment: Do you have any other columns in the table?

Comment: Yes I have 20 another column like ID etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE for that

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT DosyaNo, SiraNo, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DosyaNo ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rnum
  FROM table1
)
UPDATE cte
   SET SiraNo = rnum
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34acc/1)** demo

Comment: Query is Ok in my scratchpad table but its not ok in original table.

Comment: Its OK i am soryy i had made a problem. thank you so much 
for interested in